# Jest/Enzyme Test firing Child prop as function in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have seen numerous examples on testing a simulate or child prop as function in react class components, I'm trying to test something similar for functional components. Looks like child onClick is not being fired.

my-component.jsx

```
const myComponent = () => {
const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
const clickedVal = () => {
    setVal(prev => prev + 1);
  };
return (
 <Paper variant="outlined">
   <IconButton onClick={() => clickedVal()}>
    <MaterialUIIcon/>
   </IconButton>
<Child val={val}/>
</Paper>
)
}
```

I tried below,

my-component.test.jsx

```
it("test", () => {
wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
const child = wrapper.find(Child);
const iconButton = wrapper.find(IconButton)
console.log(`beforeClick ${child.prop("val")}`);
iconButton.simulate("click")
console.log(`afterClick ${child.prop("val")}`);
```

I don't see the value change at all, I tried the following too
`iconButton.prop("onClick)();`
`iconButton.props().onClick();`
nothings seems to be working, I see beforeClick afterClick value as 0. Is there a different way to invoke child prop function in functional components?

Comment: Your code looks good. add a console.log inside clickedVal and see if it is getting executed. May be the way you are accessing val in the child is wrong. Also try wrapper.update() after simulating click

Comment: @soumyasunny I just checked with console.log inside clickedVal it is executing and I can see the value is getting updated in my code from 0 to 1 but still `console.log(`afterClick ${child.prop("val")}`);` is showing as 0. I tried adding wrapper.update() after simulate it is not making any difference

Answer (score 0):

I got it, where it was going wrong,
after simulating the event, instead of calling the prop val on child I had the find the Child component again and then get prop val like below

```
it("test", () => {
wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
const child = wrapper.find(Child);
const iconButton = wrapper.find(IconButton)
console.log(`beforeClick ${child.prop("val")}`); // val is 0
iconButton.simulate("click")
console.log(`afterClick ${wrapper.find(Child).prop("val")}`);// val is 1
```

Thanks @soumyasunny, once I saw clickedVal is being executed I changed the way I'm accessing the props and it worked!